# SlickGrid cells floating

Tags: css, slickgrid

I'm trying to make a grid using SlickGrid for editing of some records in an ASP.NET MVC project.

At the moment I'm unable to figure out how to make the records actually appear as a table. The SlickGrid is appearing like this:
[image: Grid as it is now]

I've been looking in my stylesheets and javascript files for things that might cause this but I'm not really sure what I should be looking for. Can anyone be of assistance?

As far as I can tell I followed the SlickGrid example pretty closely.

**Stylesheet includes:**

```
<link href="../../Content/SlickGrid/slick.grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/SlickGrid/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Javascript includes:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom/js/jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery.jsonp-2.4.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.editors.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.remotemodel.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/SlickGrid/slick.grid.js"></script>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
    var columns = [
        { id: "FileTypeId", name: "File Type", field: "FileTypeId", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer, sortable: false },
        { id: "DateCp", name: "Date/CP", field: "DateCp", editor: Slick.Editors.Date, sortable: false },
        { id: "VesselId", name: "Vessel", field: "VesselId", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer, sortable: false },
        { id: "FixtureNo", name: "Fixture No", field: "FixtureNo", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: false },
        { id: "VoyageNo", name: "Voy No", field: "VoyageNo", editor: Slick.Editors.Integer, sortable: false },
        { id: "VegoilVoyageNo", name: "Vegoil Voy No", field: "VegoilVoyageNo", editor: Slick.Editors.Text, sortable: false },
        { id: "Remarks", name: "Remarks", field: "Remarks", editor: Slick.Editors.LongText, sortable: false }
    ];
    var options = {
        editable: true,
        enableAddRow: true,
        enableCellNavigation: true,
        asyncEditorLoading: false,
        enableColumnReorder: false,
        autoEdit: true
    };

    var grid;
    $(function () {
        $.getJSON('<%= Url.Action("BoxFiles", "Box", new { id = Model.Id }) %>', function (data) {
            grid = new Slick.Grid("#files", data, columns, options);
            grid.render();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you please post your JS code?

Comment: Added in. Any ideas? I also tried commenting out Site.css as well but the cells still do not render as a grid, so pretty sure that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

The `slick.grid.css` style sheet needs to be included **after** `jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css`.

Comment: This changed some of the cell styles but doesn't do anything for the cell alignment.